# Yii2: How to capitalize in a text field?

Tags: yii2, capitalize

I have this text field and I need to capitalize (uppercase the first letter) when the user types a word:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
```

**Example.** I have this:

[image: lower-case]

But I need this:

[image: upper-case]

Maybe I have to use jQuery (I prefer not to use it :) ).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply capitalize the first letter of a word by using the **text-transform** property of **CSS** which controls text case and capitalization.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <input type="text" name="Name" style="text-transform:capitalize" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it adding `'style' => 'text-transform:capitalize'`:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'style' => 'text-transform:capitalize']) ?>
```

Comment: you can add this info in the question.